# FCM Push API Returns 400 Bad request

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below is my code to create connection pull for to send fcm push. This connection pull create at the time of application start.

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@PostConstruct
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {      
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
     connectionManager.setMaxTotal(3);
     connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(3);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(90000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

And below is the code to send Push.

```
json.put("to", target.trim());
        info.put("title","title");
        info.put("body","body");
        json.put("notification", info);

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "key=" + "mygoogleapikey");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",entity,String.class);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        if(jsonObj.getInt("failure") == 0 ) {
            log.info("Success");
        }else {
            log.info("Failed");
        }
```

My Application is running on AWS cloud, when application start then it works fine means sends push to device but after some time when above code try to send push which gives me 400 Bad Request.

I am not understanding where is going wrong.

**Update :** 
I have printed Json Payload which send to fcm which is as below

```
{"notification":{"title":"Test Push","body":"Test Push completed successfully"},"to":"sdffggg:bjvfbmnfjhfgjkdfhgjkhdfmngjmdfhgjkhfjmgbdfmnbmnvbkkk"}
```

and getting below error from Spring Rest Template

```
[org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91), org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615), org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573), org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529), org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:329)
..............
.................
```

Comment: Can you log the result of json.toString() and check that it conforms to the spec for the notification payload?  It looks like you're trying to use the legacy spec: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your response. You mean json.put("to", target.trim()); ... this json? Can you please provide me a sample json for this.

Comment: @ppb did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm also getting the same error.

Comment: It is very much possible that the device or target you are sending this request has uninstalled the app.